# Using VoiceXML built-in types in SRGS grammar

Tags: numbers, grammar, speech-recognition, voicexml

I am trying to create a custom grammar for a sentence containing a number, e.g. (Revenue increased by 34.5 billion dollars).

A rule that I created using W3C specification looks like:

```
      <rule id="root" scope="public">  
        <item> <ruleref uri="#subject"/> </item>
        <item> <ruleref uri="#direction"/> </item>
        <item> <ruleref uri="#thenumber"/> </item>  
      </rule>
```

To pick up the numeric part of the sentence, I want to leverage a built-in type of VoiceXML (e.g.)

```
<grammar type="application/srgs+xml" src="/grammars/number.grxml"/>
```

or alternatively use some sort of library for number patterns. The last alternative would be to create a set of rules from scratch to recognize any number.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the VoiceXML standard built-in types support natural number input.

Check with your platform or speech recognition vendor.  They may offer what you want, which is a natural money grammar (en-US).  Alternatively, you can write a natural number grammar.  They aren't trivial, but the pattern of input for English isn't too difficult.  I've written one before, but I don't own the rights to it.  It is a fairly common grammar for most professional services and platform vendors in the speech recognition industry.

Comment: The VoiceXML standard actually does specify that built-in types are optional.  However, it does specify a "number" type specifically for natural number input.  As you stated, @codechobo will need to check the documentation for his specific VoiceXML browser and ASR engine, but the major ones I've used all support natural numbers as a built-in type.  More info: http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/#dmlABuiltins